# Javascript return only the subdomain part of a string url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string that is typically a url (minus the http/www part). Keep in mind this string is returned via an API and not parsed from the browser url.

```
For eg "xyz.abc.com or "login.xyz.abc.com"
```

Now I need to parse the string and return only the subdomain so that I get the following:

```
"xyz" and "login.xyz"
```

With Python, I can achieve this using the following code:

```
".".join(String.split(".")[:-2])
```

I am unable to find the appropriate syntax or equivalent in javascript.

Comment: not sure I understand the downvote. I could not find an answer for this in stack-overflow. also I provided a working example in python which means I tried to make this work, but couldnt do it in javascript

Comment: You can use almost the same code in Javascript: https://jsfiddle.net/kLvrtdzs/

Comment: @Alexandre this fails for `google.co.uk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure that the URL will always have a subdomain (it won't be just `abc.com`, for example), and that the top-level domain will always consist of one part (it won't be `co.uk`, for example), you could do this with the following JavaScript:

```js
const exampleURL = "login.xyz.abc.com";
const splitURL = exampleURL.split(".");
const subdomains = splitURL.slice(0, splitURL.length - 2); // Remove the domain
const subdomainsString = subdomains.join(".")
console.log(subdomainsString)
```

However, keep in mind that the conditions I mentioned above are two pretty big ifs: if an URL is returned as `example.co.uk`, this method would think that `example` would be the subdomain.

Comment: Javascript's `Array.prototype.slice` can handle negative "end" index, so you could write just `const subdomains = splitURL.slice(0, -2);`.